# Please How can i extract all the words after each = from this string "SHORT.NAME:1=Niger,SHORT.NAME:2=Daniel,SHORT.NAME:3=GLORIA,"

Tags: php

Please How can i extract all the words after each equal to sign from this string "SHORT.NAME:1=Niger,SHORT.NAME:2=Daniel,SHORT.NAME:3=GLORIA,"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Learn keywords, `=` in your case is a delimiter. Now search for `break string by delimiter in php`. [Here is my google result](https://www.google.nl/search?q=break+string+by+delimiter+in+php) and its exactly the same as @Sammitch. Read [ask] and [mcve] before you ask your next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will "extract" and print to the screen the words between each equal sign and the following comma:

```
$str = "SHORT.NAME:1=Niger,SHORT.NAME:2=Daniel,SHORT.NAME:3=GLORIA,";

$arr = explode( ',', $str );

$shortNames = array();
foreach ( $arr AS $element ) {
  $shortNames[] = explode( '=', $element );
}

foreach ( $shortNames AS $shortName ) {
  if ( isset( $shortName[ 1 ] ) ) {
    echo $shortName[ 1 ] . '<br>';  // replace this line
  }
}
```

You can replace `echo $shortName[ 1 ] . '<br>';` with whatever you actually want to do with the words.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but learn where to answer. Hopefully a `-6` answer will be deleted and your earned reputation will go down the drain. Also `$shortNames = array();` is obsolete.

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Congrats! You just did someone else's work in exchange for meaningless internet points!